# MVC: Returning Multiple Rows of data to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor, viewmodel

I have a table with several rows of data that I need to return to the controller. In my view, I initially load the table by selection of a time period and clicking a button. The table loads all my relevant records but one of my table cells contains a dropdown list. So I should be able make a selection in the dropdown click "update" and my controller saves the changes.

So everything works until I try and save. The model that is sent to the controller is completely null. The list property I have tied to the table cells returns to the controller null.

```
 @ModelType SuperViewModel
 //We need this a view model in order to store a List of the models in the table   

 @Using (Html.BeginForm())
 @For Each i in Model.CompleteList
    Dim currentItem = i //MVC auto-generated extra declarations. Seems redundant to me but it works.
 @<table>
 <tr>
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(function(Model)currentItem.Name)</td>
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(function(Model)currentItem.SampleTime)</td>
 <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(function(Model)currentItem.WorkTime, ViewBag.WorkTimeList)</td>
 </tr>
 Next
 </table>
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update"/>
 End Using

 //Controller
 <HttpPost()>
 function Save(vmodel as SuperViewModel, submit as String) as ActionResult //NOTE: submit parameter is used because we have two submit buttons but its not relevant here
      if submit = "Update"
            db.Entry(vmodel.CompleteList).State = EntityState.Modified//Here the exception is throw because our list is null at this point even tho its tied to the model in the view.
            db.SaveChanges()
      end if
 End Function
```

NOTE: This is written in VB.NET but C# help is welcome. I am familiar with both languages in MVC.

Comment: How is SuperViewModel defined?

Comment: There's several properties in it but the one that applies here is the "CompleteList" which is a List(Of AnotherModel). Which that other model was generated by Entity Framework based of our DB table.

Comment: Is there a `Next` missing before `End Using` to close the `For Each`? Also, can you add some of the markup rendered by the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use a for iterator and have the view use the indexed element for the HTML element. I don't know the VB.NET syntax, c# example is below. This allows the model binder to correctly determine the element in the view model so that it can repopulate the view model on postback.

```
<table>
 @For(var i = 0; i < Model.CompleteList.Count; i++) 
{
 <tr>
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model.CompleteList[i].Name)</td>
 <td>@Html.DisplayFor(Model.CompleteList[i]..SampleTime)</td>
 <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(Model.CompleteList[i]..WorkTime, ViewBag.WorkTimeList)</td>
 </tr>
}
 </table>
```

Your post method should then work fine.

Comment: This is correct. We were not binding our rows to specific instances in our list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It might be returning null due to some conflicts in the parameter name (the parameter names used must be used some where else as well). Try this

```
<input name="subButton" type="submit" value="Update"/>
```

and change

```
function Save(vm as SuperViewModel, subButton as String) as ActionResult
```

Comment: That didn't work. The SuperViewModel is still null when it hits the controller.

Comment: Refer to this [blog post] (http://codeblog.shawson.co.uk/mvc-strongly-typed-view-returns-a-null-model-on-post-back/)

Comment: That blog didn't really help. I added the ModelState Validation. It passes that if but the view model is still null.

Answer (score 0):

I would need to see the names in the markup generated by the `DropDownListFor`, but I suspect it is because with `currentItem` you are binding against the `CompleteList` type, but your controller method is expecting the full `SuperViewModel` type. There is nowhere in the code you have shown that I see you binding to the `SuperViewModel` type.

Try changing your controller method to:

```
<HttpPost()>
 function Save(currentItem as CompleteList, submit as String) as ActionResult //NOTE: submit parameter is used because we have two submit buttons but its not relevant here
      if submit = "Update"
            db.Entry(vmodel).State = EntityState.Modified//Here the exception is throw because our list is null at this point even tho its tied to the model in the view.
            db.SaveChanges()
      end if
 End Function
```

The `WorkTime` property should be populated with the selected value from the DropDownList.

**Edit:** changed the parameter name to match the binding name.

Comment: <select name="$VB$Local_currentItem.AdjustedTime"> This is the tag for the dropdown list

Comment: <select name="$VB$Local_currentItem.AdjustedTime"> This is the tag for the dropdown list. Are you saying the second declaration below the `For Each` is causing MVC to not recognize the binding to the model?

Comment: Interesting. I'm not familiar with VB version of model binding, but the reason you are getting Nothing (or nulls) is because the model binder can't map the values to your controller parameters. It looks to me like the model expects to map to something called `currentItem As CompleteList`.

Comment: Yes, the naming is very important. The model binding will try to map things with the same name as long as they can be cast to the requested type.

Comment: Yea I just commented out the second dim and changed all my displayfor/hiddenfor to  `@Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) i.SequenceNumber)@Html.DisplayFor(Function(Model) i.SequenceNumber)` With no success. Still receiving nulls(Nothings)

Comment: Watch name of the parameter on your controller as well, it has to match or the model binding still won't work. If the old name was `_currentItem` then your parameter should be named `currentItem` (see my edited answer above).